# Pocket hole screws instead of screws

Tags: wood, woodworking, screws

I've read much discussion stemming from people asking if screws can be used in place of pocket screws. However, I have the converse question: if a DIY plan calls for 2" screws, can I use 2" pocket screws instead?

I know that some might say it depends on what I am building. I am building: http://www.ana-white.com/2010/01/plans/tryde-console-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pocket screw" refers to the position and angle of the screw more than the type of screw. Screws used in pocket hole joints tend to be self-tapping, but are otherwise the same as any other screw with the same diameter, length, and thread coarseness. They can definitely be used in place of other screws.